# What is the correct way to smooth sharp edges between faces?

Tags: edges

I have the model for the Owl tutorial from Blender's YT channel. You can see on the nose that there are some lines caused when using the mirror modifier. I tried to play around with the smoothing tool but this didn't seem to work. I also tried a smooth modifier but didn't get what I was looking for.

If you delete the edges that also didn't work.

What is the correct way to remove those lines and make the faces continuous?[image]

Comment: It looks as if you might have a couple of hidden faces under the mesh. Try looking at it in Edit in wireframe mode and see if any internal faces are in the model. If there are you should be able to delete them.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to vertex selection mode.

1. Select all the vertices.
2. Got to mesh option on the top.
3. Clean up > merge by distance.
   This will delete the unwanted vertcies.
   If this does not work, you  should go to face select mode and apply correct normals ( shortcut : ctrl+ N, in edit mode obviously.
   [image]
   If you see any red color that means some thing is wrong. You need recalculate normals. If every thing you see from out side is blue then you are good to go.
   Againg if it does not work just apply your mirror modifier on object mode and then give it a subdivision surface modifier then smoth shading.
   Hope it helps.!